# Vim generate text expansion from shortcut

Tags: vim

The codebase I'm working on requires standard comments around any modifications that we make:

```
// -----------ABCD---------------
```

and then

```
// ----------\ABCD---------------
```

What's the best way to map a short combination of keys like `-abcd` and `\abcd` to generate these longer strings?

Comment: There was a new plugin on [r/vim](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/) named [Prismo](https://github.com/guywald1/vim-prismo) which aids with decorative comments. This maybe helpful for your situation, but not exactly what you are requesting. The reddit post can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/6ylnt8/made_a_plugin_to_beautify_your_titles/).

Comment: It's probably overkill for me; but probably useful for someone whose search ends up here. Didn't realize there was a Vim SE till I looked at your user profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, built-in `:help abbreviations`:

```
inoreab abcd // -----------ABCD---------------
inoreab abcD // ----------\ABCD---------------
```

Why did I choose different triggers? There are some rules (documented as "three types of abbreviations" under the above help link) for the allowed keys; the easiest is that it's all keyword characters.

If you insist on those exact triggers, you'd have to fiddle with the `'iskeyword'` option (which can affect syntax highlighting and motions!), or switch to `:inoremap`. The downside of that is that you won't see the typed characters until any ambiguity has been resolved (try it; you'll see what I mean).

#### ABCD is just a dummy; I need dynamic text here

If multiple abbreviations won't do, you'll need *snippets*.

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion) and [this comparison by Mark Weber](http://vim-wiki.mawercer.de/wiki/topic/text-snippets-skeletons-templates.html).

A snippet would look like this (snipMate syntax):

```
snippet abcd
    // -----------${1:ABCD}---------------
    ${2:content}
    // ----------\$1---------------
    ${3}
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up adding `ab abcd //----------abcd-----------` and `ab dcba //---------\abcd-----------` to my `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Yeah, I had thought about those, too, but then decided against using that as an example because the inverted one seems difficult to type.